# Calling userdefined PLSQL functions in TimesTen database query

Tags: sql, function, plsql, timesten

How to call PLSQL functions inside the query of TimesTen database. When I am calling, it is giving such error

> 2818: Unknown function GET_COSTPRICE. If this is a PLSQL function note that such functions are not yet supported in SQL statements.
>
> The command failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimesTen just told you that's not possible:

> note that such functions are not yet supported in SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can call PLSQL only inside pl/sql blocks

```
BEGIN
  :res=GET_COSTPRICE()
END;
```